# How pulsar can handle ack between broker and consumer

Tags: apache-pulsar

I was so curious about the case when consumer consume a message, then it send ack to broker. Broker receive the ack and send ack back to consumer but due to connection lost or some other issues that make this ack cannot receive by consumer.

So how pulsar handle this case? Is there any config in golang that I can use for it?

Answer (score 3):

When a subscription is created, Pulsar retains all the messages, even if the consumer is disconnected. The retained messages are discarded only when a consumer acknowledges that all these messages are processed successfully.

Also, as far as I know, broker doesn't send ack back to consumer; consumer sends the ack to broker after successfully consuming the message/messages.
If consumer didn't send ack to broker due to disconnect, broker assumes that message has not received by the consumer and resends it.

[Reference](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/2.11.x/concepts-messaging/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20subscription,resend%20this%20message)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, the broker will receive the message ACK from the consumer and update the cursor position in the subscription to ensure the message isn't re-delivered. Once the cursor position is updated, the broker sends the ACK_RESPONSE back to the client.

Upon receipt of the ACK_RESPONSE message, the client removes the associated message from its internal list of un-ACKed messages. What happens next depends on the AckTimeout policy set on the client.

Nothing happens if the [AckTimeout](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/2.11.x/concepts-messaging/#acknowledgment-timeout) is set to zero, and you have "at most once" processing semantics. Otherwise, after the AckTimeout expires, the client sends a REDELIVER_UNACKNOWLEDGED_MESSAGES command to the broker, which triggers resending all the messages on the subscription that the broker has NOT already received an ACK.

In your scenario, since the ACK did reach the broker, the message in question would NOT get resent after the ack timeout.

I cover this in greater detail in my Pulsar Summit [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUlEBnF7XUg). Unfortunately, I don't see a way to configure the AckTimeout in the Go [Consumer](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go/pulsar#ConsumerOptions), but I might be missing it.